# Drools Project Build Fails using ArrayList Condition

Tags: maven, arraylist, compiler-errors, drools

I'm having trouble building a kjar with maven when any of the .drl files contain an ArrayList conditional.

For example, here is a rule from the tutorial that is causing this issue. I tested this with other rules as well, and I receive the same build error whenever there is a conditional parameter inside the ArrayList parenthesis--e.g. ArrayList(size >= 2). The build is successful when I rewrite the rule to omit the conditional inside the parenthesis and add and eval statement to check for the size of the ArrayList. Normally, I would simply rewrite the rule, but there are hundreds of rules in our local repository that use this syntax, and rewriting all of them would set us back. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I am using drools-core and compiler 7.73.0.Final and building using the maven command line tool. I've copied the full stack trace below the two rules. The specific error I receive is this:

java_util_ArrayList_Metadata_INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field, lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (230:31373) : var_total_2_sCoPe cannot be resolved to a variable]

Build Fails:

```
rule "More than 2 CashFlow Lines"
when
    $c : Account( $acc : accountNo )
    $p : AccountPeriod ($sDate : startDate ,$eDate : endDate )
    $number : ArrayList(size >= 2 )
          from collect( CashFlow( mvtDate >= $sDate && mvtDate  <= $eDate,accountNo == $acc ) )
then
    showResults.showText("Found 2 or more CashFlow Lines");
    showResults.showText("<<<<<<<<<<");
    for (Object ff : $number){
        showResults.showText(ff.toString());
    }
    showResults.showText(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
```

end

Build Success:

```
rule "More than 2 CashFlow Lines"
when
    $c : Account( $acc : accountNo )
    $p : AccountPeriod ($sDate : startDate ,$eDate : endDate )
    $number : ArrayList( )
          from collect( CashFlow( mvtDate >= $sDate && mvtDate  <= $eDate,accountNo == $acc ) )
    eval($number.size() >= 2)
then
    showResults.showText("Found 2 or more CashFlow Lines");
    showResults.showText("<<<<<<<<<<");
    for (Object ff : $number){
        showResults.showText(ff.toString());
    }
    showResults.showText(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
```

end

Stack trace for build failure:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.73.0.Final:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project DroolsTest: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.73.0.Final:generateModel failed: [lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (55:5353) : java_util_ArrayList_Metadata_INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field, lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (230:31373) : var_total_2_sCoPe cannot be resolved to a variable] -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.73.0.Final:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project DroolsTest: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.73.0.Final:generateModel failed: [lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (55:5353) : java_util_ArrayList_Metadata_INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field, lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (230:31373) : var_total_2_sCoPe cannot be resolved to a variable]
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.73.0.Final:generateModel failed: [lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (55:5353) : java_util_ArrayList_Metadata_INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field, lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (230:31373) : var_total_2_sCoPe cannot be resolved to a variable]
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompilerException: [lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (55:5353) : java_util_ArrayList_Metadata_INSTANCE cannot be resolved or is not a field, lesson3/Rules6538e27aa082454c8a6b7537bf609bdeRuleMethods1.java (230:31373) : var_total_2_sCoPe cannot be resolved to a variable]
at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad (KieMemoryCompiler.java:135)
at org.kie.maven.plugin.GenerateCodeUtil.compileAndWriteClasses (GenerateCodeUtil.java:77)
at org.kie.maven.plugin.GenerateModelMojo.generateModel (GenerateModelMojo.java:157)
at org.kie.maven.plugin.GenerateModelMojo.execute (GenerateModelMojo.java:112)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "the tutorial" is, but your rule has a typo:

```
$number : ArrayList(>= 2 ) from collect( ... )
```

What exactly is supposed to be compared to 2? Probably size:

```
$number : ArrayList(size >= 2) from collect( ... )
```

That being said, the rule you claim 'works' is no good. If $number is an ArrayList, then there's no way the eval could ever work: `eval( $number >= 2 )`.

Comment: Apologies. That was a notepad find and replace error. The syntax of the rule has been updated with references to the size variable and method of the ArrayList. Whenever there is a boolean expression included within the ArrayList expression, the build fails.

Comment: I also tested this without specifying the specific List implementation and the project builds without error. $number : List(>= 2 ) from collect( ... )